# Find the dimension of the Eigen-space corresponding to the Eigen value $ \ \lambda \ $ with respect to $ \ \vec v \ $

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

Let $ \ V \ $ be a finite dimensional vector space over the field $ \ \mathbb{C} \ $  and $ \ T: V \to V \ $ be a linear transformation.

Suppose $ \ \lambda \ $ is a Eigenvalue of $ \ T \ $.

Let the characteristics polynomial and minimal polynomial of $ \ T \ $ be respectively given by $ \ \chi(\lambda)=(z-\lambda)^m \ $ and $ \ m(\lambda)=z-\lambda \ $ .

If $ \ \vec v \ $ be the Jordan basis of $ \ T \ $ , then find $ \ dim \ E(\lambda , \ \vec v) \ $ or the dimension of the Eigen-space corresponding to the Eigen value $ \ \lambda \ $ with respect to $ \ \vec v \ $.

Also find the Jordan matrix $ \ \mathcal{M} (T) \ $

**Answer:**

Since the characteristic polynomial of $ \ T \ $ is  $ \ \chi(\lambda)=(z-\lambda)^m \ $ ,  we have  $ \ dim (V)=m \ $ ,

Now the algebraic multiplicity of $ \ \lambda \ $ is $ \ m \ $.

Since the minimal polynomial of $ \ T \ $ is $ \ m(\lambda)=z-\lambda \ $ , the geometric multiplicity of $ \ \lambda \ $ is also $ \ m \ $.

Thus the dimension of the Eigen space $ \ E(\lambda)  \ $ of  $ \ \lambda \ $ is given by

$ dim \ E(\lambda)=m \ $

**Am I right so far?**

So there is a jordan block of size $ \ m \ $ as follows:

$$ \mathcal{M}(T)=\begin{pmatrix} \lambda & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda &  0 & \cdots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & & & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & & \cdots & \lambda \end{pmatrix} $$

**Am I right so far?**

Comment: If the minimal polynomial is $z-\lambda$, by definition $T-\lambda I=0$. Therefore $T=\lambda I$. Which means that all vectors are eigenvectors corresponding to the eigevalue $\lambda$. All the remaining information is not needed: The characteristic polynomial, the finite-dimensionality of $V$, even that $T$ is linear is not needed. Everything follows from knowing that the minimal polynomial is that simple.

Comment: @LB_O "that $T$ is linear is not needed." How do you define the minimal polynomial of a *non-linear* transformation?

Comment: Can someone answer the question ?

Comment: @user539887 Just lookup the definition of minimal polynomial and change nothing. All you need is a function $f:V\to V$ where $V$ is a vector space, or even less, a module over the ring of coefficients of the polynomial.

Comment: @yourmath I already answered the question: Since the minimal polynomial is $z-\lambda$, then $T$ is equal to multiplication by $\lambda$. Therefore, all vectors are eigenvectors, the dimension of the eigenspace for $\lambda$ is the dimension of $V$, and in any basis the matrix of $T$ is diagonal with $\lambda$ in the diagonal. In particular, that is its Jordan form.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right.  For justification, see Wikipedia subtopic ["Complex matrices"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form#Complex_matrices) in the "Jordan normal form" article.